# ArangoDB - Backup and restore all data

Tags: database, arangodb, database-backups

My aim is to create the arango database dump (with all the users and passwords, permissions, databases, collections, roles and so on) and then make a full restore of this data on the other arango server (that was installed from scratch and empty).

I am using the one-node configuration, arangodb version is **3.4.4 [linux]**.

On origin I make a dump of every database:

```
USER=root
PASSWORD=***
for db in $(arangosh --server.username "$USER" --server.password "$PASSWORD" --javascript.execute-string "db._databases().forEach(function(db) { print(db); });")
do
  arangodump --output-directory /tmp/dump/"$db" --overwrite true --server.username "$USER" --server.password "$PASSWORD" --include-system-collections --server.database "$db"
done
```

Then I move the created folders to the empty arangodb server on this server go with:

```
arangorestore --input-directory "/tmp/dump/_system/"
arangorestore --input-directory "/tmp/dump/collection/"
arangorestore --input-directory "/tmp/dump/collection2/"
...one by one
```

The result if very far my expectations, I just get the collections in **_system** database for the **root** user (no other users, no databases).

What am I doing wrong? How can I make the full backup and restore?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`arangorestore` needs to be told to which database to restore the data to. This can be achieved by providing the `--server.database` option in the same way as it can be done for `arangodump`.
If no value is provided for `--server.database` it will default to `_system`, meaning the subsequent invocations of arangorestore will each overwrite the previous data in the `_system` database.

If the target databases do not exist yet on the backup server, it is possible to create them on the fly using the option `--create-database true`.
Additionally, to restore system collections, `arangorestore` needs to be given the option `--include-system-collections true`.

That means, if your databases are really named "collection" and "collection2", your restore commands should look as follows:

```
arangorestore --input-directory "/tmp/dump/_system/" --server.database "_system" --include-system-collections true --create-database true
arangorestore --input-directory "/tmp/dump/collection/" --server.database "collection" --include-system-collections true --create-database true
arangorestore --input-directory "/tmp/dump/collection2/" --server.database "collection2" --include-system-collections true --create-database true
```

Please also note that with ArangoDB 3.5 there is an option `--all-databases` for both arangodump and arangorestore, which should greatly simplify the backup and restore process.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is ArangoDB 3.5 already released? Can't find it

Answer (score 1):

**To take dump from remote server or local server execute the command**

```sh
arangodump --server.endpoint tcp://ip_address:8529 --server.username test --server.password test --server.database dev --output-directory "dump"
```

**To restore from dump execute the below command**

```sh
arangorestore --server.endpoint tcp://ip_address:8529 --server.username test --server.password test --server.database dev --input-directory "dump"
```